# How to remove noise near the edge of an object in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, background-color, image-segmentation

I have an image like this:

[image: Input image containing noise]

I would like to remove the background(part A) near the edge of the object. I plan to use color detection since the color of object and noise are a little bit different. But maybe it is not a good idea.

I would appreciate if you could have any idea for me.
Thanks

Comment: You could state exactly what is the difference you perceive between the "noise" and the object edge

Comment: @belisarius: Thanks for comment. I think it is not precisely to call it "noise". I mean the background (part A), where the color is light green. The object part is the part which has dark green.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're performing any sort of color-based segmentation of images, you may find it easier to convert to [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) first to select specific color ranges. I outline how you can do this sort of thing in [an answer I gave to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color/4064205#4064205). The steps you would likely want to follow would be the following:

- Convert to HSV and create a binary mask by selecting pixels with hues within a green color range and with a minimum amount of saturation and value.
- Erode the resulting mask by a certain amount to remove small spurious clusters.
- Dilate the eroded mask to get back to a smoother edge for your selected pixels.

I can't give an *exact* example of how you would apply this analysis to your data since the image you provide in the question actually has a higher resolution than the data it displays, but here's a general solution that uses the functions [RGB2HSV](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rgb2hsv.html), [IMERODE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imerode.html), and [IMDILATE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imdilate.html) (the last two are from the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/#thd1)):

```
rgbImage = imread('data.jpg');  %# Load the RGB image
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);   %# Convert to HSV color space
hPlane = 360.*hsvImage(:,:,1);  %# Get the hue plane, scaled from 0 to 360
vPlane = hsvImage(:,:,3);       %# Get the value plane
mask = (hPlane >= 80) & (hPlane <= 140) & (vPlane >= 0.3);  %# Select a mask
SE = strel('disk',10);                 %# Create a disk-shaped element
mask = imdilate(imerode(mask,SE),SE);  %# Erode and dilate the mask
```

And here's some code to visualize the edges created by the above analysis:

```
edgeMask = mask-imerode(mask,strel('disk',1));  %# Create an edge mask
edgeImage = zeros([size(edges) 3]);     %# Create an RGB image for the edge
edgeImage(find(edgeMask)) = 1;          %#   that's colored red
image(rgbImage);                        %# Plot the original image
hold on;
image(edgeImage,'AlphaData',edgeMask);  %# Plot the edge image over it
```

[image]