# How to count objects in an image using K-Means matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, k-means, image-segmentation

I want to count how many peanuts there are in this picture using image segmentation K-MEANS ,
does anyone know how to go about this?

[image: peanutzzzz]

Comment: For future reference, please refrain from phrasing your question like "gimme the codezz plz"; at least show [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989818/how-to-count-number-objects-in-an-image-identify-by-color-in-matlab).

Comment: as @RodyOldenhuis says, please, ask specific questions. don't just ask people to make your program!

Comment: correlation clustering is a better suited objective function for clustering where the main aim is detecting the underlying number of clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but still. I would use the clustering in order to separate the peanuts from the background. But a color thresholding or a dominant color analysis should be enough and give comparable results. Except that I would consider each dark area (shadows) as the background in order to separate the peanuts.

Then you get a binary mask, and you can apply an ultimate eroded in order to estimate the number of peanuts.