# Hue/ saturation values of orange color

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb, grayscale

I am new to image processing and matlab. I am trying to extract the orange color from my image. Just similar to the example in this page [How can I convert an RGB image to grayscale but keep one color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color)  instead of the red color I want to get the color range of orange color..

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several online tools for converting between RGB and HSV, if you don't need to do this automatically. The first three google hits seem to do this:

http://web.forret.com/tools/color.asp

http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx

http://www.csgnetwork.com/csgcolorsel4.html

If you don't know the RGB value of orange, or any other color, then you could use a color picker.

[This](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm) actually has an HSV converter as well.

And orange is 256/128/0 in RGB or 30 (degrees), 100%, 100% in HSV.