# check an image pixel by pixel for specific rgb values in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, pixel

I want to read an RGB image(.jpg) from a folder in MATLAB, scan each pixel of the image and check if it has a specific color (for example if it is Violet:`R 128,G 0, B 255`) and count how many pixels have this specific color.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Is this a homework? If so, please retag it as homework.

Comment: no its not a homework.. is a part of a personal project

Comment: @user1439660: Instead of doing color comparison in RGB, you could convert to a different colorspace to select your color. Something like this: [How can I convert an RGB image to grayscale but keep one color?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064205/97160)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the image is loaded into variable named `A`:

```
 pixelMask =  A(:,:,1) == 128 & A(:,:,2) == 0 & A(:,:,3) == 255;
 count = nnz(pixelMask);
```

Another way is to use `bxsfun` and singleton expansion:

```
 pixel = cat(3,128,0,255);
 S = all(bsxfun(@eq, A, pixel), 3);
 count = nnz(S);
```

Comment: in the second solution, you could write: `S = all(bsxfun(@eq, A, pixel), 3);` instead