# After Thresholding, Extracting the white color portion from the Image in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, pixel, tesseract

I'm uploading an image, from that image I want to get the white color rectangular portion which contains some numbers or even if I get the location means the pixel values of that whole rectangular portion it will be sufficient for me.
I want to send that block of image to Tesseract for Image Processing,
Can anyone tell me How can I get it ?

Note - I do not want to use OpenCV.

[image: Sample Image]

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: This May Help <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but that link contains logic which is in matlab as i don't know how to implement matlab in android. I wanted it in Java or in android. Is it possible ?

Comment: What Format has your Image Data? RGB, RGBA, Grayscale? Do you only need the lower white Rectangle or both? What have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks for your response, My Image is in RGBA format and ya I need only the lower white rectangle which is containing numbers. And so far I have done is that I have applied threshold to the original image to get that particular portion highlighted and removing the unwanted portion.

Comment: What is the expected range of variation in the image? Are these photos always taken from the same angle and distance under the same lighting conditions? Is there likely to be random background clutter? Could you perhaps provide a few different sample images? (And don't threshold them first — that isn't really helping.)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, The angle maybe different always (may not be the same every-time) and the distance may be sufficient for the human eye to read.
In threshold only I'm removing the background so that we can get only the yellow color region.
Yes I'm uploading some of the images, before thresholding
Here is the link

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yqqls.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oqp4k.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SZVSX.jpg
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jnQ5I.jpg