# count number of non gray pixels in RGB image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have a RGB image which has only black and white squares. I want to count number to non gray pixels in this image. I am new to matlab. I want to check the quality of image as it should only contain black and white pixels.Actually I have undistorted this image due that some colored fringes are appeared.I want to know the how many color are introduced to check the quality of the image.

Comment: How do you define non-gray pixels or even gray pixels in a RGB image that has only black and white squares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using matlab to get counts of specific pixel values in an image.

Images are RGBA <512x512x4 uint8> when read into matlab (although we can disregard the alpha channel).

Something like this

```
count = sum(im(:, :, 1) == 255 & im(:, :, 3) == 255 & im(:, :, 3) == 255);
```

will give you the count of such pixels. Replace sum with find to get the indices of those pixels if you need that.

Comment: This count is number non grey pixels in an image?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/25368-selecting-and-removing-all-grey-pixels-in-an-rgb-image follow this link u will get your exact answer. Do opposite of what they are saying

Comment: however above code will also work but i havent tested just let me know if error is there

Answer (score 0):

> A pixel is said to be gray if its R,G,B components are all same.

Using this logic

```
%// checking for equality of R,G,B values
B = any(diff(im,[],3),3);  %// selecting only non-gray pixels
count = sum(B(:));         %// Number of non-gray pixels
```

PS: This answer is tailored from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475422/check-element-wise-equality-of-a-3d-matrix-matlab/29475859#29475859) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064144/2111163) answer.