# Replace defined colors of a source image with a background image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to write a function that takes 4 parameters:
to change the blue background of an image and replace it with other image

Comment: Can you provide what have you tried so that we can help

Comment: Well then go ahead and write the function... Then put up your question along with the code...

Comment: What is the `blue color`?

Comment: What is the purpose of threshold? Which pixels of background image should be replaced, the ones which have the same color as `color` or the pixels which are in the same location as the removed pixels in the original image? The problem is badly formulated.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bluescreen(A,B,c,thresh)
A = imread(A);
B = imread(B);
Ar = A(:,:,1);
Ag = A(:,:,2);
Ab = A(:,:,3);
Br = B(:,:,1);
Bg = B(:,:,2);
Bb = B(:,:,3);
logmap = zeros([size(A,1),size(A,2)]);
logmap = (Ar > (c(1)-thresh)).*(Ar < (c(1)+thresh)).*...
     (Ag > (c(2)-thresh)).*(Ag < (c(2)+thresh)).*...
     (Ab > (c(3)-thresh)).*(Ab < (c(3)+thresh));
Ar(logmap == 1) = Br(logmap == 1);
Ag(logmap == 1) = Bg(logmap == 1); 
Ab(logmap == 1) = Bb(logmap == 1);
A = cat(3 ,Ar,Ag,Ab);
imshow(A);
end
```

When you call it like,
`bluescreen('peppers.png','tape.png',[200 10 10],50);`

It gives you,

[image]

I'm not sure what you want!

Ok. I cut both images and called `bluescreen('A.png','B.png',[30 30 120],80);`

I get this,

[image]

I think It is good enough, don't you?!

Comment: i used the code in my picture and it didn't work so i change the value of blue color after find the RGB color for blue pixels[63 93 130] but it didn't work so i change the threshold and this what i get!its looks like a noisy picture . sorry for asking many question http://store2.up-00.com/2014-10/1414350711211.png ....http://store1.up-00.com/2014-10/1414352144521.png

Comment: @khulood, check the answer now. make sure that both your images have same size and have `png` or `jpg` format.

Comment: i call the function as you call it but it didn't work, did you change any thing in the code ?

Comment: @khulood, No I haven't. I think you can't upload images so email me your original pictures. you can find my email in my profile.

Comment: @kamtal, please, delete your first answer as this is the correct one.