# Compare colour variations for an image using MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I intended to choose one point of the image and compare other points' RGB　values with this point's, and then change the similar points' colors, but I failed. Following is my code:

```
function exchangecolor()
I1=imread('F:\28.jpg');   
I2=imread('F:\29.jpg'); 
[m1,n1,x1]=(size(I1));
[m2,n2,x2]=size(I2);  //[399,400,3]=size(I1)=size（I2)
r1=I1(200,200,1);  
r2=I2(200,200,1);

g1=I1(200,200,2);
g2=I2(200,200,2);

b1=I1(200,200,3);
b2=I2(200,200,3);

for i=1:m1
    for j=1:n1
        if abs(I1(i,j,1)-r1)<=10
            if abs(I1(i,j,2)-g1)<=10
                if abs(I1(i,j,3)-b1)<=10
                    I1(i,j,1)=r2;
                    I1(i,j,2)=g2;
                    I1(i,j,3)=b2;
                end
            end
        end
    end
  end
imwrite(I1,'F:\89.jpg','jpg');
```

Comment: In what way did you fail?

Comment: Example images, if you have rights to post them, would help a lot too. Simple logic is only going to work on very easy images.

Comment: @Oliver I failed because the 'similar' points I got from the comparison are incorrect. In other words, I failed to find the similar points.

Comment: @Neil Sorry, I don't have the right. The images I choosed are similar except the clothes' colors.

Comment: @Smile you might find [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color) relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the correctness of your code, but nested loops and if clauses is not the Matlab-ish way of doing stuff.

Have you considered this approach:

```
rgb1 = I1(200,200,:);
rgb2 = I2(200,200,:);
sel = all( abs( bsxfun(@minus, I1, rgb1) ) <= 10, 3 );%//need care when subtracting `uint` type!
% replace
for ci=1:3
    tmp = I1(:,:,ci);
    tmp(sel) = rgb2(ci);
    I1(:,:,ci) = tmp;
end
```

The only thing I can think of that might be problematic here is that `I1` is probably of type `uint8` and for some reason Matlab is having hard time subtracting `rgb1` from `I1`. Try casting `I1` to `double` and see if it helps.

---

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice. I'm a beginner. I will pay more attention to my variable names next time.

Comment: But the code you offer doesn't work very well. I think my logic isn't practical.