# How to keep a color in an image while discarding others in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I want to keep a particular color in an image and discard all other colors.
When I try to keep red color the program works but when I try a similar approach for green color I get nothing.
Can anyone help.
Below is my program. can't post images due to some reputation thing.

```
a = imread('image.jpg');
b = rgb2hsv(a);
h = 360 .* b(:,:,1);
s = b(:,:,2);
v = b(:,:,3);
nonred = (h > 20) & (h < 340);
v(nonred)=0;
b(:,:,3)=v;
c=hsv2rgb(b);
```

And here is the code for green color

```
a = imread('image.jpg.');
b = rgb2hsv(a);
h = 360 .* b(:,:,1);
s = b(:,:,2);
v = b(:,:,3);
nongreen = (h > 210) & (h < 30);
v(nongreen) = 0;
b(:,:,3)=v;
c=hsv2rgb(b);
```

Comment: What does googling `matlab keep one color` return?

Comment: This is a close-to-duplicate that might help you - probably not close enough to close this as an exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is on the line:

```
nongreen = (h > 210) & (h < 30);
```

Which no value of h can satisfy. i.e. you're looking for h greater than 210 AND less than 30.

As your angular range for hue is between 0-360, you can just OR instead:

```
nongreen = (h > 210) | (h < 30);
```