# MATLAB - How to eliminate shadowed background on an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, matlab-cvst

I am trying to process a picture. There is an RGB leaf photograph and I want to exract the leaf's itself only.

The procedure I follow is

1. I read image from file
2. Convert to grayscale
3. Apply 5x5 median filter
4. Convert to BW

[image]

[image]

As you see the shadow on the bottom right corner sticks to the BW image. Is there a method to select the leaf only.

```
I = imread(files{404});

hcsc = vision.ColorSpaceConverter;        
hcsc.Conversion = 'RGB to intensity';       
Ig = step(hcsc, I);

medFilt= vision.MedianFilter([f f]);
Ig = step(medFilt, Ig);

at = vision.Autothresholder;        
Ibw = step(at, Ig);
```

Comment: Why do you convert to grayscale? You could perhaps convert to HSV and select the leaf based on a hue range. See [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064205/2586922)

Comment: @LuisMendo I have never thought that. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting to grayscale image, I convert it to HSV and take its **V** part. It results better now.

```
I = imread(files{404});

I = rgb2hsv(I);

Ig = I(:,:,3);

medFilt= vision.MedianFilter([f f]);
Ig = step(medFilt, Ig);

at = vision.Autothresholder;        
Ibw = step(at, Ig);
```

[image]