# Trying to apply a color map to a bar graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a collection of data that I am trying to graph as a histogram. Additionally, I would like to color the individual bars as a function of the x axis location. [CData](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#input_argument_namevalue_d119e63137), described here seems to do what I want but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
h = bar(new_edge,N,'hist','FaceColor','flat');
hold on

for n = 1:length(N)
    if (x - x/1.09) - (x-1) > 0
        probability(n) = 1 - ((x-x/1.09) - (x-1))/((x - 1/1.09)+(x/0.91 - x)); 
    else
        probability(n) = 1;
    end

    color_num = 30;
    cm = jet(color_num);
    min = 0.5450;
    max = 1;

    color_map_index = floor(1 + (probability(n) - min)/(max-min)*(color_num-1));
    rbg = cm(color_map_index,:);

    h.CData(n,:) = rbg;

end
```

Similar to the MATLAB example, I first create my bar graph. Next, I want to loop through and prescribe the color for each bar based on a calculation. I do this by creating a colormap with # of bins and a min/max, getting a color index, then finally retrieving the rbg value. I get the following error when I try to apply the color:

*Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.*

*h.CData(n,:) = rbg;*

If I dive into the h object, MATLAB tells me that CData has a size of (4x65). What's going on here? Both `new_edge` and `N` are 1x65 vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem with your Matlab version. 
When I test CData with bar on 2017b, this works:

```
openExample('graphics/ControlIndividualBarColorsExample')
```

When I try it on 2017a, it doesn't run. 
Does the example work?

Comment: I think you're on to it. The example does not work either, so this must be a version thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that the error you're getting ("Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals") is coming from the following line?:

```
h.CData(n,:) = rbg;
```

Since we know `n` is a positive integer greater than or equal to one, the indexing here shouldn't have a problem. It's more likely that your error is coming from the line above it (i.e. the value for `color_map_index` is less than 1). I would double-check how you are computing `color_map_index`.

You could also try using [function notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/accessing-the-properties-and-methods-of-objects.html#f13-5802) (i.e. [`get`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)) instead of [dot notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/accessing-the-properties-and-methods-of-objects.html#f13-5788) to update the property:

```
cData = get(h, 'CData');
cData(n, :) = rbg;
set(h, 'CData', cData);
```

Incidentally, you should also not be giving your variables the same name as existing functions, like you are doing here:

```
...
min = 0.5450;
max = 1;
...
```

This shadows the built-in [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) and [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) functions, which [can also lead to the same error message under other conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20054047/52738). Definitely rename those.

If you are still having trouble after trying those fixes, you could try setting the color using indexed color mapping instead, as illustrated in [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064205/52738) (near the bottom). As a simple example, the following plots 20 bars of 30 different possible values, then colors them based on their height:

```
color_num = 30;
N = randi(color_num, 1, 20);
hBar = bar(N, 'hist');
colormap(parula(color_num));
set(hBar, 'CData', N, 'CDataMapping', 'direct');
```

And the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a version control problem, there's really not a clean solution. In case anyone else comes along with a similar question and has the same version, here's a workaround that worked for me in 2017a.

Rather than creating a bar chart, you can simply draw rectangles. It's messy, but it does produce the desired [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBAwF.png).

```
[N,edges] = histcounts(AB(AB<2));

probability = zeros(1,length(N));
new_edge = zeros(1,length(N));

for m = 1:length(N)
    new_edge(m) = (edges(m) + edges(m+1))/2;
end

figure
hold on

for n = 1:length(N)
    x = new_edge(n);
    if ((x - x/1.09) - (x-1)) > 0
        probability(n) = 1 - ((x-x/1.09) - (x-1))./((x - x/1.09)+(x/0.91 - x)); 
    else
        probability(n) = 1;
    end

    color_num = 100;
    cm = jet(color_num);
    min = 0;
    max = 1;

    color_map_index(n) = floor(1 + (probability(n) - min)/(max-min)*(color_num-1));
    rbg = cm(color_map_index(n),:);

    rectangle('Position',[edges(n),0,(edges(n+1)-edges(n)),N(n)],'Edgecolor','k','FaceColor',rbg)

end

set(gcf,'color','w');
blah = colorbar;
```