# Change the color of bar element in Matlab bar graph?

Tags: matlab, graph, colors

how can I change the color of one of my bar element in the bar graph? Because it seems my Matlab version (2015b) doesn't let me use either b.LineWidth b.EdgeColor Or CData. my code is something like below;

```
b = bar(1:30); 
b.FaceColor = 'flat'; 
[bv,bi] = max(1:30); 
b(bi).LineWidth = 2;
b(bi).EdgeColor = 'red';
```

With this error for using b.LineWidth and b.EdgeColor;

No public property LineWidth exists for class matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder. Error in tt (line 5)

and the error for using CData;

```
b = bar(1:30); 
b.FaceColor = 'flat'; 
[bv,bi] = max(1:30);
b.CData(bi) = [0.4,0.4,0.4];
```

No appropriate method, property, or field 'CData' for class 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't have `LineWidth` or `EdgeColor`? [The documentation for R2015b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/ref/bar.html#namevaluepairs) states otherwise. This is also all explicitly addressed in the [9th example in the R2015b documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthxche).

Comment: Yes, definitely. It is the error;
No appropriate method, property, or field 'CData' for class 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.

Error in tt (line 5)
b.CData(bi) = [0.4,0.4,0.4];

Comment: and also for the others;
No public property LineWidth exists for class matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder.

Error in tt (line 5)
    b(bi).LineWidth = 2;

Comment: `matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder` means you're not properly addressing the output of `bar`. Please [edit] your post to contain a [mcve].

Comment: I made it. thank you

Comment: There is not supposed to be a 'CData' property. `b.LineWidth = 3` works as expected, as does `b.FaceColor = [0.4,0.4,0.4]` and `b.EdgeColor=[1,0,0]`. (R2017a, but following docs for R2015b linked by excaza.)

Comment: `b(bi).LineWidth = 2;` is nowhere in the code you've provided. Again, please read [mcve]. If you don't do this, we can't help you.

Comment: `b` is a scalar, you can't index into it. By doing `b(bi)` you are adding "null" handles to the array `b`, which of course have no properties.

Comment: ok, what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

(I just learned something new today!)

It seems that `bar` has [two main modes of operation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthf_ju-style), producing different handle graphics object types. The `style` input argument selects the mode of operation:

- `bar(...,'grouped')` or `bar(...,'stacked')` produces a `Bar` object. Note that `grouped` is the default style.
- `bar(...,'hist')` or `bar(...,'histc')` produces a `Patch` object.

[The documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthf_ju-style) does not specify that the `hist` mode produces a different object type. [In R2015b these same options existed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/ref/bar.html#inputarg_style), I presume the output types were the same as they are with my version of MATLAB (R2017a).

The `Bar` object produced by the first mode does not have a `CData` property. There is a `FaceColor` and `EdgeColor` property. See the [`Bar` properties documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.bar-properties.html) for more information. But note that this is a single object, so you cannot index into the handle and set properties for individual bars. The properties control all bars at the same time:

```
b = bar(1:30); 
b.FaceColor = 'flat'; 
b.LineWidth = 2;
b.EdgeColor = 'red';
```

The exception is the `XData` and `YData` property, which have one value per bar.

The `Patch` object produced by the second mode does have a `CData` property. It's a bit more complex to manipulate, because the `Patch` has coordinates for each vertex and each edge. But the `CData` property can be set in different ways depending on your needs. Set to a `N`x1 array (with `N` the number of bars) it gives an index into the color map for each bar (but see also the axis' `Clim` property for how that index is interpreted). Set to a `N`x1x3 array it gives an RGB triplet for each bar. See the [`Patch` properties documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.patch-properties.html) for more information. Here is an example:

```
b = bar(1:30,'hist'); 
b.FaceColor = 'flat'; 
b.LineWidth = 2;
b.EdgeColor = 'red';
cols = zeros(30,1,3)+0.5;
cols(5,1,:) = [1,0,0];
b.CData = cols;
```

[Credit to [gnovice in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168632/7328782).]

Comment: Thank you so much @Cris Luengo. I was wondering how I can set the FaceColor to e.x. blue?

Comment: If you want them all the same color, simply do `b.FaceColor='blue'`, If you want them all blue except for one, use the `hist` mode, and set `cols=zeros(30,1,3); cols(:,1,3)=1; cols(5,1,:)=[1,0,0]; b.CData=cols;` or something to that extent