# Can not apply colormap on a barchart

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, colormap

I am trying to apply a [colormap](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) on my bar chart in matlab. It should be a simple thing to do if you read the short explanation given on the web page of matlab but I still can't make it.

```
b = bar(cell2mat(data_plot'))
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
ylabel('Some Label');
xlabel('Some Label')  
colormap (bar, copper)
```

I don't get a [copper](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copper.html) color map, it is the same as it was. I have also tried the following command:

```
colormap copper
```

Still no results. Can someone tell me, what my mistake is ?

Comment: I assume you get an error, because your code is broken, right?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149168/trying-to-apply-a-color-map-to-a-bar-graph-in-matlab) what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct use is

```
colormap copper
```

However the result is probably not what you expect because if you use the colormap like this all bars will have the first color of the chosen map.

You can achieve what I think you want to see by using a loop and individually color the bars:

```
y = [1 3 5; 3 2 7; 3 4 2];
fHand = figure;
aHand = axes('parent', fHand);
hold(aHand, 'on')
colors = copper(numel(y));
for i = 1:numel(y)
    bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', colors(i,:));
end
```

[image: Output of bar chart]

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you please explain me, what exactly are you doing with **'parent'**?

Comment: The approach here is that we create a "parent" figure `fHand` and a parent axes `aHand` and then assign the individual bar charts as children to this parent axes, by specifying that the parent is `aHand`.