# How to show values on heatmap have different color

Tags: matlab

I am trying to have bar chart that has color according to its value. I can get the bar chart and heatmap separate but not together.

as well as CData and vals2colormap. But it didn't work form. 
Please some help :)

Here are the commands I try to combine:

```
h = bar(t,retndecm(:,1),"stacked");
l = heatmap(t, retndecm(:,1)','Colormap',jet);
```

Comment: Is this what you want?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149168/trying-to-apply-a-color-map-to-a-bar-graph-in-matlab

Comment: Yes that is correct but I can't do that on my dataset. any more help?

Comment: You need to be considerably more specific! Why would a method not be aplicable to your dataset? Can you post a [mcve] showing how you tried and why it does not work, so we can help you fix it?

Comment: Thank you, here is what I tried:   N = X(1:10,1);
h = bar(N, 'hist');
cData = get(h, 'CData');
h.CData(n,:) = rbg;
set(h, 'CData', cData); but I want to give different color to the bar chart according to their value/height

Comment: please [edit] your question with the information

Comment: I can't edit my question, I am new to this website. can you still help?

Comment: Just click on this link: [edit]. It should open the question for editing. Otherwise, just below the tags, it shays "share edit close ...."