# I want to color bar chart based on values/heights

Tags: matlab

I am trying to have bar chart that has color according to its value. I can get the bar chart and heatmap separate but not together.

Here are the commands I try to combine:

```
N = X(1:10,1);
h = bar(N, 'hist');
cData = get(h, 'CData');
h.CData(n,:) = rbg;
set(h, 'CData', cData);
```

Comment: Please do not repost questions. Edit your previous one, or this one, to add all the required information, but do not repeat them. I have now closed your older question.

Comment: In addition to that, please take your time to read what a [mcve] is. In this case, your example is not an [mcve], because its not reproducible (we do not have `X` nor `rgb`, we do not know how it looks) nor a good example for the same reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested in version R2018b. The colours of the bars are determined by the `FaceColor` and `EdgeColor` properties by default, not directly by the `CData` property. The `CData` property is only used when `FaceColor` is set to `'flat'`.

Here is a short example using `bar(Y)`.
[image: Resulting image]

```
n_groups = 4;
n_data_per_group = 5;

Y = rand(n_groups, n_data_per_group);

h = bar(Y);
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat');
for i = 1:n_data_per_group
    h(i).CData = Y(:, i);
end

colorbar
```

Alternatively, as suggested by [gnovice's solution in the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168632/12156872), one can use `bar(Y, 'hist')` to make `Patch` objects instead of `Bar` objects. A slight modification in his example to accommodate for multiple groups of data is given below.
[image: Resulting image]

```
n_groups = 4;
n_data_per_group = 5;

Y = rand(n_groups, n_data_per_group);
h = bar(Y, 'hist');
set(h, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
for i = 1:n_data_per_group
    h(i).CData = Y(:, i);
end

colorbar
```

The main observable difference between the two methods is the default spacing between the bars.

Comment: Thank you Michael, it was very helpful. I really appreciate it. 

But the problem is when I test it with just one set of data it doesn't work properly. 

Can you please have a look at below code: 

    Y = [.1 .25 .3 .7 .4 .5 6.3 .10 1.2 3.5 1.5];
    h = bar(Y, 'hist');
    set(h, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
    h.CData = Y;
    colorbar(Y)

I want to have indexed color for this set. Let's say 'jet'.

Comment: It looks like your data Y is a row vector. I think the CData property need to be a column vector for your case. So when you try to assign CData, use h.CData = Y'. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, it works now but only on random data, when I use real obs. it gives me one color bar chart not indexed color.

Comment: Let's say X = [0.03 
0.01 
0.03 
(0.02)
(0.00)
0.01 
(0.03)
(0.01)
0.02 
(0.04)
(0.01)
0.03 
(0.02)
0.01 
0.03 
0.01 
0.00 
(0.02)
0.02 
(0.00)
0.01 
(0.02)
(0.05)
0.00 
(0.01)
0.02 
0.01 
0.00 ] '    h = bar(X);
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat');
    h.CData = X';

colorbar(X)

Comment: I also want to change the color set to something called "jet"

Comment: I fixed thanks, I use the below codes: set(groot,'DefaultFigureColormap',jet);
h = bar(Y,.99); 
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat'); 
h.CData = Y'; 
caxis([min(#) max(#)]);
colorbar(N);

Comment: In your example with X = [0.03 ...], the only missing bit is caxis. Alternatively, use set(gca, 'CLim', [#, #]). If you think the response answers your question, please select it as the accepted answer :)