# How to segment this image, based on texture?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, object-detection, image-segmentation

I need to segment the below image, into stover (the green-white stuff) and maize kernel (the yellow-white object).

[image: maize]

I've done this already with CNN's, but I need to compare it with "classical image processing". I've tried this already with color and HOG, but it did not give the desired result.

Does anyone has better ideas?

Comment: With regard to segmentation by color, there are some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4063965/52738) you could try.

Answer (score -1):

Before CNNs segmentation by Level-Sets was all the rage.

Check out this informative link (don't worry its not mine):
https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/11/20/levelset-segmentation/